# How can I implement GMail OAuth 2.0 on server using PHP?

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

How can I implement OAuth 2.0 on server using PHP to create/update email accounts for our domain. Most examples use $CLIENT_SECRET witch I don't have, may be it's old way or something. Here is a code I wrote:

```
createEmail('azzozhsn@domain', 'password', 'Azzoz', 'Al-hasani');



function createEmail($username, $password, $firstName, $lastName)
{
$p12key             = file_get_contents('file.p12');
$APIkey             = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$clientId           = 'YYYYYYYYYYcipbi.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$emailAddress       = 'ZZZZZZZZZZ@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$certFingerprints   = 'WWWWWWWWWWW';
$user2impersonate   = 'admin@domain';

require_once('Google/autoload.php');

$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user');
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
     $clientId,
     $scopes,
     $p12key
);
$cred->sub = $user2impersonate;

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);    

$user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
$name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();

$name->setFamilyName($lastName);
$name->setGivenName($firstName);

$user->setName($name);
$user->setHashFunction("MD5");
$user->setPrimaryEmail($username);
$user->setPassword(hash("md5", $password));
$user->setExternalIds(array("value"=>28790,"type"=>"custom","customType"=>"EmployeeID"));

$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$result = $service->users->insert($user);
return $result;
}
```

then with some debugging I Found this message:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "authError",
"message": "Invalid Credentials",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

I know the problem is in the authentication but I don't know how to do it, most codes I found use client_secret witch I don't have. It like old method or something...

Comment: I think you can find this link https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2   helpful to create *client_secret* for your API. If you are using Auth 2.0 then you need to create Client ID, Client Secret as per that link.

Comment: yeah, when I create "web application" account, it requres me to sign in to complete the process. and I don't want that. When I add "Service account" witch I want. I don't konw how to impelent it.

Answer (score 1):

After working all night I got the answer.
First, I think I mixed up between  $clientId and $emailAddress Then I need to get $client->getAccessToken() and refresh it when it expires.

```
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('GmailAdmin');

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $emailAddress,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'),
    $key
);
$cred->sub = user2impersonate;
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
```